# Outlook Addin screen size in window object gives incorrect width and height

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an event based Outlook addin with an ItemSend Event. When the user clicks on the Send button, I need to open a dialog using the displayDialogAsync. Since this only accepts a percentage for width/height I am calculating the ideal percentage based on the screen size for my content to fit without any scroll bars or extra space.

This works fine on Outlook Web but is not working fine for Outlook Windows.

This issue is reproducible when you have 2 screens with different resolutions and the dialog is opened on the screen which is not the main display. For example a laptop screen and an external screen.

The width/height retrieved from any of the below parameters are of the main display set in Windows Display settings and not where the compose window or even the main outlook window is opened.

- window.screen.height / window.screen.width
- window.screen.availHeight / window.screen.availWidth

Other parameters such as window.innerHeight or window.outerHeight gives much worse numbers which doesn't even make sense (getting 80 or 118 in some of the fields on a 4k screen)

XML manifest ItemSend event

`<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events"> <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="onItemSendHandler" />  </ExtensionPoint>`

Expected behaviour is for any of the parameters of window object to give the correct width/height depending where the compose window is opened and ultimately where the dialog will be opened.